# A regex for the last use of a word in a string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to figure out how to grab the tail end of a string using a word as a delimiter, but that word can be used anywhere in the string. So only the last use would start the grab.

example: `Go by the office and pickup milk by the safeway BY tomorrow`

I want to grab the `by tomorrow` and not the other `by`s

This is the regex I'm trying to make robust:

```
$pattern = '/^(.*?)(@.*?)?(\sBY\s.*?)?(@.*)?$/i';
```

I think a negative lookahead would do it, but I've never used one before

Thanks!

Comment: HEY! It was a look ahead solution. Here's what I came up with incase anyone has the same problem or wants to show be a cleaner way of doing it...

Comment: $pattern = '/^(.*?)(@.*?)?(\sBY(?!.*by)\s.*?)?(@.*)?$/i';

Comment: But that pattern won't work if you have a string like `Go by the office and pick up a disk by the safeway of 2048 bytes.` It's kind of necessary to have the word boundaries or spaces at least in the negative lookahead.

Comment: Great point Jerry, I forgot about the by in a word case. Good catch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what are the other things you have in the regex for, but here's the one I would use:

```
$pattern = '/\bby\s(?!.*\bby\b).*?$/i';
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/fT3nA7)

`\b` is word boundary and will match only between a `\w` and a `\W` character or at string beginning/end.

`by` matches `by` literally.

`\s` matches a space (also matches newlines, tabs, form feeds, carriage returns)

`(?!.*\bby\b)` is the negative lookahead and will prevent a match if there is another word `by` ahead.

`.*?$` is to get the remaining part of the string till the end of the string.

Comment: OMG! The regex101demo website is amazing! Finally a decent REGEX sandbox. Wow thanks for turning me on to that.

Comment: @user3452624 You're welcome! I find it amazing too! The only problem I find with it is that there's no split, and it doesn't support C# flavoured regex, but that's fine. It works for almost everything else :)

Answer (score 2):

To match the last `BY` (uppercase and lowercase letters) try this regex:

```
\b[bB][yY]\b(?!.*\b[bB][yY]\b.*)
```

see demo here http://regex101.com/r/uA2rL0

This uses the `\b` word boundary to avoid matching things like `nearby` and as you said a negative lookahead.